# SQL script to with the shown screenshot

Tags: sql

I want to write a sql script to as shown in the screenshot image. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGo5G.png)

I've tried `MAX()` function to aggregate the `ESSBASE_MONTH` field to make it distinct and display a single month in the output instead of multiple months. I am yet to figure out how to put 0 in any month that EMPID did not perform any sale like in December under  "Total GreaterThan 24 HE Account" and "Total_HE_Accounts"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields of the table are not very informative however based on screenshot, this is the best answer I could come up with.

Assuming the table name is SALES;

```
select 
    ADJ_EMPID, 
    ESSBASE_MONTH, 
    MAX(YTD_COUNT) AS YTD_COUNT, 
    SUM(TOTAL_24) AS TOTAL_24, 
    SUM(TOTAL_ACC) AS TOTAL_ACC 
from SALES
group by 
    ADJ_EMPID, 
    ESSBASE_MONTH
```

The above will aggregate the monthly 'sales' data as expected.

To add the 'missing' rows such as the `December`, it is possible to do it by doing a union of the above query with a vitural table.

```
select 
    MAX(MONTH_NUMBER) AS MONTH_NUMBER,
    ADJ_EMPID, 
    ESSBASE_MONTH, 
    MAX(YTD_COUNT) AS YTD_COUNT, 
    SUM(TOTAL_24) AS TOTAL_24, 
    SUM(TOTAL_ACC) AS TOTAL_ACC 
from (
  select 
        1 as MONTH_NUMBER,
        *
    from SALES 
  union all
  select * from (values 
      (1, '300014366', 'January', 0, 0, 0), 
      (2, '300014366', 'Feburary', 0, 0, 0), 
      -- add the other missing months as required
      (11, '300014366', 'November', 0, 0, 0), 
      (12, '300014366', 'December', 0, 0, 0)
  ) TEMP_TABLE (MONTH_NUMBER, ADJ_EMPID, ESSBASE_MONTH, YTD_COUNT, TOTAL_24, TOTAL_ACC)
) as AGGREGATED_DATA 
group by 
    ADJ_EMPID, 
    ESSBASE_MONTH
order by MONTH_NUMBER;
```

`TEMP_TABLE` is a vitural tables which contains all the months and sales as zero. There is a special field `MONTH_NUMBER` added to sort the months in the proper order.

Not the easiest query to understand, the requirement is not exactly feasible either..

Link to [fiddledb](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pF4UZhFKZih6K8ckonKpNj/2) for a working solution with PostgreSQL 15.

Comment: Thank you for this @atish.s

I should be able to implement this logic to what I am looking for, else I will be coming back with more questions and hopefully more clarity.